# How to retrieve xml from my webservice in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I'm using a webservice in php here :

http://cdt33.tourinsoft.com/soft/RechercheDynamique/Syndication/controle/syndication2.asmx

You can test for example `getListing` with `idModule = dafda774-317d-4b5f-bb8b-33e5977dc13c`, and click on `invoke`

I'm trying to retrieve this result (XML) in php. But i have no idea how to do this.

If i use getListing like :

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://cdt33.tourinsoft.com/soft/RechercheDynamique/Syndication/controle/syndication2.asmx?wsdl");

echo "GET LISTING";
$getListing = $client->getListing(
    array (
        'idModule' => "dafda774-317d-4b5f-bb8b-33e5977dc13c"));
echo("<pre>");
print_r($getListing);
echo("</pre>");
```

Result is something like that :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [getListingResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [schema] => 
            [any] => 
HOTAQU03301V3EZB2005-06-29T00:00:00.0000000+02:002012-06-28T14:43:44.0000000+02:0074HOTHÃ´tellerie1e9eb500-e0c9-4a53-b6a5-0b36faa63ed4true 2 Ã©toiles FranÃ§ais www.hotel-lenovel.com +33 5 57 52 26 47 7 oui En centre ville$ Au bord de la mer Ascenseur$ Salon 22 -1.164866 Au coeur d'Arcachon, Ã  deux pas de la gare, du thÃ©Ã¢tre de l'Olympia et de l'Office du Tourisme, le Novel bÃ©nÃ©ficie d'une situation privilÃ©giÃ©e. Les chambres sont chaleureuses et douillettes pour un sÃ©jour....... ETC
```

How can i retieve XML ?? Thanks you !

Comment: Check the API docs to see if it has an xml output mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sometihng to try out, run it and check the source code for the page, it should contain the xml file. SOAP is just a fancy way of doing a post.

```
<?php
function smartpost($type,$host,$port='80',$path='/',$data='') {
    $d="";
    $str="";
    $_err = 'lib sockets::'.__FUNCTION__.'(): ';
    switch($type) { case 'http': $type = ''; case 'ssl': continue; default: die($_err.'bad $type'); } if(!ctype_digit($port)) die($_err.'bad port');
    if(!empty($data)) foreach($data AS $k => $v) $str .= urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v).'&'; $str = substr($str,0,-1);


    $fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errno,$errstr,$timeout=30);
    if(!$fp) die($_err.$errstr.$errno); else {
        fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($str)."\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($fp, $str."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) $d .= fgets($fp,4096);
        fclose($fp);
        $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $d, 2);

        $header = isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : '';
        $content = isset($result[1]) ? $result[1] : '';

    } return array($header, $content);
}

list($header, $content) = smartpost('http','cdt33.tourinsoft.com','80','/soft/RechercheDynamique/Syndication/controle/syndication2.asmx/getListingByIDs',array('idModule'=>'dafda774-317d-4b5f-bb8b-33e5977dc13c','ObjetTourCode' => '','IDs' => ''));
print($content);
?>
```

Comment: I have this error : Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to http://cdt33.tourinsoft.com/soft/RechercheDynamique/Syndication/controle/syndication2.asmx/getListingByIDs:80 (Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?), and fsockopen is enable.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud , I don't have anything to test it on and like I said it has been a couple years, but I think I fixed the error you were getting.

Comment: No, the result is juste an empty html page.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Try running it in a from this: <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 include("test.php");
?> where test.php is the name of the file.  And check for errors in the result or in the logs.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud alright, I tested this one out, just look at the source code for the resulting webpage, your xml will be stored in the $content variable.

Comment: Very very nice :) Thanks you :D

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using standard PHP SoapClient, try using

```
$client->__getLastRequestHeaders()
```

(http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php)
According to maual, you should also set trace option to true on SoapClient:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://cdt33.tourinsoft.com/soft/RechercheDynamique/Syndication/controle/syndication2.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => true));
```

Regards, Jakub Derda

Answer (score 0):

class ABRSoapClient extends SoapClient
 {

```
$result = "";

function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) 
{

    $result =  parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version); 
    return $result;

}
```

}

Instead of creating object of SoapClient, Create object of ABRSoapClient, Here $result is your XML string from Web-Service.

You can access that variable using $client->result;